# Need an efficient way to change factor values from one column of a data frame to another columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am currently dealing with categorical data in `data.frame` where two of the columns are type factor. It has around 9000 total rows with over 40 levels. Currently I am changing those columns to characters first because I was getting `NA` values when I try to change them with their factor form. After I change these columns to characters, I was able to change them, and then I change the type of column back to factors.

Here is my approach code:

```r
library(dplyr)

#model data frame
df <- data.frame(A= as.factor(c("Jerry", "Kelly","Kelly", "Lion", "Zebra", "Bear", "Kelly")), 
                 B= as.factor(c("Eats", "Jumps", "Roasts", "Roars", "Runs", "Sleeps", "Jumps")))
glimpse(df)

#Observations: 7
#Variables: 2
#$ A <fct> Jerry, Kelly, Kelly, Lion, Zebra, Bear, Kelly
#$ B <fct> Eats, Jumps, Roasts, Roars, Runs, Sleeps, Jumps

#select those factor columns and change their type
df[c("A","B")] <- lapply(df[ c("A", "B")], as.character)

glimpse(df)
#Variables: 2
#$ A <chr> "Jerry", "Kelly", "Kelly", "Lion", "Zebra", "Bear", "K...
#$ B <chr> "Eats", "Jumps", "Roasts", "Roars", "Runs", "Sleeps", ...

#now I want to change Kelly's actions for example                           
df<- within(df,B[A %in% c("Kelly")] <- "CHANGED")
print(df)

#      A       B
#1 Jerry    Eats
#2 Kelly CHANGED
#3 Kelly CHANGED
#4  Lion   Roars
#5 Zebra    Runs
#6  Bear  Sleeps
#7 Kelly CHANGED

#Then I change it back
df[c("A","B")] <- lapply(df[ c("A", "B")], as.factor)

glimpse(df)
#Observations: 7
#Variables: 2
#$ A <fct> Jerry, Kelly, Kelly, Lion, Zebra, Bear, Kelly
#$ B <fct> Eats, CHANGED, CHANGED, Roars, Runs, Sleeps, CHANGED
```

Problem is, character way method is not a good approach from the data I am working with. Is there an alternative method where I can make factor/levels to factor/levels conversion in a neat way? Tested with unique functions to make character column behave like levels, but I am sure I am missing some knowledge.

Comment: As an alt, why not read them in as characters and then update them so that you only need to set them to factor once

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am working on someone else's script file. So I don't know whether I should I go there an change his code. I am tasked with the categorizing, and portion where data loading and cleaning is done.

Comment: fair enough; but you can add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the data loading portion

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely correct. Let me dig into his code some more, I don't want to mess up something after I do that. You know, I told that a** just do that, but he didn't listen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `fct_collapse` and it returns a `factor` with new `levels`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
    mutate(B = fct_collapse(B, CHANGED = as.character(B)[A== "Kelly"]))

glimpse(df)
#Rows: 7
#Columns: 2
#$ A <fct> Jerry, Kelly, Kelly, Lion, Zebra, Bear, Kelly
#$ B <fct> Eats, CHANGED, CHANGED, Roars, Runs, Sleeps, CHANGED
```

Comment: First time I have seen forcats package, quick question if you don't mind. Can I select multiple levels in a `c()` forms, like say if I want to change Kelly and Jerry, so can it be: `df %<>%
    mutate(B = fct_collapse(B, CHANGED = as.character(B)[A== c("Jerry", "Kelly")]))??

Comment: @ToadPitt Change the `==` to `%in%` as `==` is for elementwise comparison.  If the vector on the rhs of `==` is of different length, it recycles (with a length 1, it is fine, but with > 1, it just 1st row compares with Jerry, 2nd row with Kelly, 3rd row with Jerry, etc. Instead use `%in%`

Comment: Gotcha boss. Thanks a lot Akrun! Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have a moment. After you gave me this answer, I tested with the data set in factor form. Strange behaviour is happening. Like  `df %<>% 
  mutate(B = fct_collapse(B, CHANGED = as.character(B)[A == "Water Pipe Leaks/Spills"]))`, it changes other factors too`Building (Abandoned/Damaged)     CHANGED` and `Grass (Overgrown)  CHANGED`. But the strange thing is, some like these remain as is `Grass (Overgrown)    Public Services ` What do you think is going on? I made a copy of those two columns `df<- data.frame(gain_df$RequestType, gain_df$Assigned_To)` 
`colnames(kd) <- c("A", "B")`

Comment: Is github ok? I will rather show you everything. I did dput() gives me a giant output.

Comment: @ToadPitt. I can't reproduce `df <- data.frame(A= as.factor(c("Water Pipe Leaks/Spills", "Building (Abandoned/Damaged)","Kelly", "Water Pipe Leaks/Spills", "Zebra", "Grass (Overgrown)", "Kelly")), 
                  B= as.factor(c("Eats", "Jumps", "Roasts", "Roars", "Runs", "Sleeps", "Jumps")));df %<>% mutate(B = fct_collapse(B, CHANGED = as.character(B)[A == "Water Pipe Leaks/Spills"]));`

Comment: https://github.com/ToadPitt/akrunSir That was me, sorry about that.

Comment: @ToadPitt To compare, I assign it to a different object `kd1 <- kd %>% mutate(B = fct_collapse(B, CHANGED = as.character(B)[A == "Water Pipe Leaks/Spills"]));  levels(kd1$B)#
[1] "Public Services"          "CHANGED"                  "Health and Public Safety" "Transportation"`

Comment: @ToadPitt If you check `as.character(kd$B[kd$A == "Water Pipe Leaks/Spills"])
 [1] "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods"
 [8] "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods"
[15] "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods" "Neighborhoods"` wherever the Neighborhoods, it would get changed to 'CHANGED'. It can also be in other rows as well ie. `sum(kd$B == "Neighborhoods", na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4315`

Comment: I get you, but I thought Changed will be in front of "Water Piple Leaks/Spills" factors only because we specifically mentioed. Yet, Changed is in front of "Grass (Overgrown)" and "Trash/Debris (Public Property)" too. Here is the image https://github.com/ToadPitt/akrunSir/blob/master/kd1.png

Comment: No, here the `CHANGED` is on the values of 'B'.  i.e. in this examplle whereever 'Neighborhood is found, it is changed to 'CHANGED' because it is based on the levels

Comment: Ohhhhhh!!! Wow, I see what you mean now. Sorry, sorry. I wasted a lot of your time. I greatly regret it sir.

Comment: @ToadPitt Not a problem.  Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this also work?

```r
df <- df %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(A == 'Kelly', 'CHANGED', B))
```

Comment: Hi Adam, this also worked. However I selected Akruns response as an answer because he was first. Thank you very much for helping, really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries! Akrun's answer might work better if you want to make the changes to factors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without turning columns into characters. One way is to add the factor level (`"CHANGED"`) which is not present in the data and then assign the values directly.

```
levels(df$B) <- c(levels(df$B), "CHANGED")
df$B[df$A == "Kelly"] <- "CHANGED"
df

#      A       B
#1 Jerry    Eats
#2 Kelly CHANGED
#3 Kelly CHANGED
#4  Lion   Roars
#5 Zebra    Runs
#6  Bear  Sleeps
#7 Kelly CHANGED
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(A= as.factor(c("Jerry", "Kelly","Kelly", "Lion", "Zebra", 
                    "Bear", "Kelly")), 
                 B= as.factor(c("Eats", "Jumps", "Roasts", "Roars", "Runs",
                    "Sleeps", "Jumps")))
```